# Saving an enum to IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: windows-phone-7, enums, save, isolatedstorage

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app.

I have an enum and I want to save a enum value to IsolatedStorageSettings.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["someKey"] = YourObject.TheEnumValue;
```

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

There's plenty of sample code for how to save/load objects:

e.g.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=VS.95).aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/MobileLOB/archive/2010/05/07/persistent-storage-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

Try writing a simple test app - you'll soon get the hang of it!

Only "gotcha" I would warn you about is to make sure you call `Save()` after setting/changing a value